# CloudKit fetchRecordChangesOperation gives a "AppDefaultZone does not support sync semantics"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit, ckfetchrecordchangesopera

I'm using a CKFetchRecordChangesOperation with a CKFetchRecordsChangeToken to grab changes and it is telling me that the "AppDefaultZone does not support sync semantics".

Here is the offending code:

```
- (void)downloadServerChangesWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionBlock
{
    // Prepare to fetch remote changes
    CKDatabase *database = [CKContainer defaultContainer].privateCloudDatabase;
    CKRecordZoneID *zoneID = [[CKRecordZoneID alloc] initWithZoneName:CKRecordZoneDefaultName ownerName:CKOwnerDefaultName];

    // Initialize fetch record changes operation
    CKFetchRecordChangesOperation *fetchRecordChangesOperation = [[CKFetchRecordChangesOperation alloc] initWithRecordZoneID:zoneID previousServerChangeToken:[self changeToken]];
    fetchRecordChangesOperation.recordChangedBlock = ^(CKRecord *record) {
        [self performRecordChange:record];
    };
    fetchRecordChangesOperation.recordWithIDWasDeletedBlock = ^(CKRecordID *recordID){
        [self performRecordDeletion:recordID];
    };
    fetchRecordChangesOperation.fetchRecordChangesCompletionBlock = ^(CKServerChangeToken *serverChangeToken, NSData *clientChangeTokenData, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            completionBlock(error);
        } else {
            [self setChangeToken:serverChangeToken];
            completionBlock(nil);
        }
    };

    // Perform the operation
    [database addOperation:fetchRecordChangesOperation];
}
```

And here is the error it is printing out

```
[PBCloudKitSyncManager] Error Downloading Data:
<CKError 0x157a2500: "Server Rejected Request" (15/2027);
server message = "AppDefaultZone does not support sync semantics";
uuid = [redacted];
container ID = "[redacted]">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by switching to a custom zone. I create the zone when I initialize CloudKit and when I go to initialize the zoneID I use this:

```
CKRecordZoneID *zoneID = [[CKRecordZoneID alloc] initWithZoneName:@"Custom Zone Name" ownerName:userRecordName];
```

where userRecordName is the record name for the CKRecord I get for the user when I call this method in the Cloudkit initialization:

```
[CKContainer defaultContainer] fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:^(CKRecordID *recordID, NSError *error) {
     if (recordID) {
         // Save the user record id
         [self saveUserRecordName:recordID.recordName];

          /...

      }
}];
```

Comment: The documentation for CKRecordZoneID states: `To specify the current user, use the CKOwnerDefaultName constant. If you specify nil or an empty string for this parameter, this method throws an exception.`

Comment: Does it mean that `CKFetchRecordChangesOperation` will not work in public database only in private?

Comment: @János the problem I was having actually dealt with the private database. So it looks to me like a CKFetchRecordChangesOperation will not work in the default zone of the public database or the private database. So to use the operation you have to create a custom zone and watch for changes in that custom zone.

Comment: @Jonathan, per your comment "CKFetchRecordChangesOperation will not work in the default zone of the public database". Can you create a custom zone in the public database ?

Comment: @user2924482 Yes, you can create a custom zone in the public database. That's what I ended up doing.

Comment: @Jonathan why didn't use CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation to use the default zone ?

Comment: how do you create custom zone in the public database?

Comment: "You cannot create custom zones in a public database." https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKRecordZone_class/index.html

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 'Zones cannot be created or modified in the public database'